# Consolidate data in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently working with data in numpy arrays, and was wondering if there was a way to group the data by a certain column and have the underlying data combined as individual arrays nested under the grouped item. That probably sounds confusing, so hopefully this example makes a bit more sense:

```
    Array_1: 
    [[x, y, z, 1],
     [x, b, z, 2],
     [a, b, z, 3],
     [a, c, z, 4]]
```

I'd like it to come out like this:

```
Array_New:
[
  [x,
    [
      [y], [
        [z],[[1],[2]]
      ]
    ],
    [
      [b], [
        [z],[[2],[3]]
      ]
    ]
...]
```

Essentially, the hierarchy I've tried to get is this:
- if the first columns match, combine everything below it under one value as a series of subarrays (not one entry like I see with `append()`). Where the second column also matches, then combine everything under one value for the second column.

So from my example using `Array_1` we would have: 
`[x]`, then under `[x]` `[y]` and `[b]`. Under `[y]` I would have `[z]` then under `[z]` `[1]` & `[2]`. Under `[b]` I would also have `[z]`, but then under `[z]` I would have `[2]` & `[3]`.

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I tried working with numpy's `vstack`/`hstack`, but couldn't get it to work. I feel like there must be a better way to do this than iterating through each entry, seeing if it matches any others, etc. Pandas' `groupby` function was close, but doesn't give you the ability to preserve this hierarcy (if there were two `b`'s in column 2 their specific `z`'s would not be assigned to a single `b`). I also tried using a `DataSet` from pandas, but I'm not very familiar with using those, so after trying for a while I figured I'd come here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is `pandas` an option ?

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/160939)

Comment: pandas is an option- I'm open to any module. I tried pandas & converted it to a DataSet but just couldn't figure out where to go from there

Comment: Could you explain why you want to create this particular structure? What do you actually need to use `Array_New` for? There is probably a much more numpythonic way to achieve your overall goal.

Comment: What is `[x]` and how is it different to `x`? Why do you have a whole bunch of single-element arrays?

Comment: Any why does `[z],[1],[2]` feature in the output?

Comment: Sorry- `[z], [1], [2]` should have been `[[z], [1],[2]]`. I've corrected it above.

Comment: The purpose of me creating this structure is to classify performance across products. I have monthly figures going back many years (1908's) for about 700 of them. Each product belongs to 1 of ~250 groups (so `[x]` & `[a]` are groups, `[y]`, `[b]`, & `[c]` are products, `[z]` is a date and the numbers are performance figures). Since there are hundreds of thousands of rows, I'm trying to output this info in a way that will allow users to review the performance. My thought was to create a structure like this one so users could call products and get an organized return series fairly quickly.

Comment: @Brumder22 you are reinventing a database. You should either use the merge/group functions in Pandas or consider SQLite which comes with Python and organise your data in tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is **exactly** what pandas is designed for. It will allow you to group, index, aggregate or filter your data in more or less any way you can imagine.

Let's start with your example array:

```
import pandas as pd

a1 = pd.DataFrame({'group':['x', 'x', 'a', 'a'],
                   'product':['y', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'date':['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4'],
                   'performance':range(1, 5)})
print(a1)

#   date group  performance product
# 0   z1     x            1       y
# 1   z2     x            2       b
# 2   z3     a            3       b
# 3   z4     a            4       c
```

> Pandas' groupby function was close, but doesn't give you the ability to preserve this hierarcy (if there were two b's in column 2 their specific z's would not be assigned to a single b).

Did you know that you can group by *multiple* columns simultaneously [by passing a list/tuple of column names to `.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes)?

```
for name, group in a1.groupby(('group', 'product')):
    print(name)
    print(group)

# ('a', 'b')
#   date group  performance product
# 2   z3     a            3       b
# ('a', 'c')
#   date group  performance product
# 3   z4     a            4       c
# ('x', 'b')
#   date group  performance product
# 1   z2     x            2       b
# ('x', 'y')
#   date group  performance product
# 0   z1     x            1       y
```

You could achieve your desired 'hierarchical' organisation using [multilevel indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

```
a1.set_index(['group', 'product'])
print(a1)

#               date  performance
# group product
# x     y         z1            1
#       b         z2            2
# a     b         z3            3
#       c         z4            4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! At first, pandas didn't like that I was passing an `ndarray` since I took your first example but used slices from the numpy array I was trying to use to build the dataframe as values for the groups. I ended up just using `read_csv` followed by `set_index` as you suggested and it now does exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Numpy can't do this, because numpy works with multidimensional rectangular/cuboidal/etc arrays. Your output array is not one of these, but a jagged array.